# Should I use a content provider with my SQLite database?

Tags: android

I want to make a database with 2 columns: name and age. Should I use a Content Provider for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You don't need to develop your own provider if you don't intend to share your data with other applications."

Otherwise, I'd use SQLite directly with SQLiteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you want other apps to access this data.  That's the purpose of a ContentProvider.  If you want to use it internally, just access the database.